# Number of squares in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p,q$ be two odd distinct primes and $n=pq$. How many squares are there in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z^*$?

I know that in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ we have exactly $\frac{p-1}2+1$ squares, but am unsure how to do this when $n$ is a product of primes. Can I just add $\frac {p-1}2$ and $\frac{q+1}2$? I know that there's an isomorphism between $\mathbb Z/pq\mathbb Z^*$ and $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z^* \times \mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z^*$.

Answer (score 1):

An element of the cartesian product is a square if and only if both components are squares. Hence in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z^* \times \mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z^*$, there are $\frac{p-1}{2} \cdot \frac{q-1}{2}$ squares, which is precisely $\frac{1}{4}$ of the number of all elements.

---

One can easily generalize this, but one has to be careful about the prime number two. In the following, the $p_i$ will be distinct **odd** primes.

If $n=2^e p_1^{e_1} \dotsb p_s^{e^s}$ with $e \in \{0,1\}$, there are $\frac{|\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z^*|}{2^s}$ squares in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z^*$.

If $n=4p_1^{e_1} \dotsb p_s^{e^s}$, there are $\frac{|\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z^*|}{2^{s+1}}$ squares in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z^*$.

If $n=2^e p_1^{e_1} \dotsb p_s^{e^s}$ with $e > 2$, there are $\frac{|\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z^*|}{2^{s+2}}$ squares in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z^*$.

The reason is that $\mathbb Z/2^e\mathbb Z^*$ is trivial for $e=1$, is cyclic for $e=2$ and is the product of two cyclic groups for $e>2$.